What type of oppression does Exodus 23:9 refer to?
In regard to Exodus 23:9 NASB:

You shall not oppress a stranger, since you yourselves know the feelings of a stranger, for you also were strangers in the land of Egypt.

I'm wondering what the difference is between the slavery or servitude system described in Exodus 21:2-11 versus what would be considered oppression in this verse.
Laws About Slavery In Exodus has good information about the servitude system of the time and how it wasn't chattel slavery, but being able to take slaves/servants in this way still seems like a form of oppression by modern standards.
If you're allowed to take people as slaves, what are you not supposed to do? What type of oppression does this verse really refer to?

The answer to this question about "oppression" is answered by the material in the same verse:

Ex 23:9 - Do not oppress a foreign resident, since you yourselves know how it feels to be foreigners; for you were foreigners in the land of Egypt.

That is, do not treat foreigners the same as you were treated in Egypt.  Later in the Torah, this law is enlarged:

Num 15:15 - The assembly is to have the same statute both for you and for the foreign resident; it is a permanent statute for the generations to come. You and the foreigner shall be the same before the LORD.
Deut 1:17 - Show no partiality in judging; hear both small and great alike. Do not be intimidated by anyone, for judgment belongs to God. And bring to me any case too difficult for you, and I will hear it.”

That is, the law, as per modern jurisprudence, is to be "blind" to the person being tried in the sense that the judgement should be the same regardless of who is being tried.
Now, it was legal to have Israelite slaves (sometimes Israelite slaves sold themselves to pay debts etc), so it is legal for Israelites to have foreign slaves.  However, there were strict laws about how slaves were to be treated, any slave, whether local or foreign could not be oppressed and beaten without rean and without limit.  By the standards of the times, Israelite law (the Torah) was very liberal and enlightened.)
For example, look at Ex 23:12 where the Israelites were instructed to allow even their slaves and foreign residents to enjoy the benefits of the Sabbath.  See also Ex 20:10.

@Dottard's answer is adequate but I would add some specifics.
One of the issues that comes up often in terms of the idea of "oppression" in the OT is working on the Sabbath. Both employers and owners of slaves had to give their workers a day of rest on the seventh day of the week.
Exodus 20:10

The seventh day is a sabbath of the Lord your God. You shall not do
any work, either you, your son or your daughter, your male or female
slave, your work animal, or the resident alien within your gates.

The warning against oppressing workers is also found in the prophets. Malachi, for example, was not alone in speaking against  depriving a laborer of his wages, taking advantage of widows and orphans, or "turning aside" a resident alien.
Malachi 3:5

I will draw near to you for judgment, and I will be swift to bear
witness: Against sorcerers, adulterers, and perjurers, those who
deprive a laborer of wages, oppress a widow or an orphan, or turn
aside a resident alien, without fearing me, says the Lord of hosts.

The above are specific examples of what the scriptures mean by "oppressing a stranger" and having "one law" for both Israelites and aliens. The rule is not limited to oppressing someone trough slavery, but also by taking advantage or them in various other ways.

The phrase in Malachi 3:5 that says, "turn aside a resident alien" is only referring to a
"foreign resident" not a "foreign slave." These were two different classes under the law, with different rights and privileges. And the phrase , "those who deprive a laborer of wages" only refers to a Hebrew servants not a foreign slave since a Hebrew servant was not to be treated as a slave but as a hired worker am' I right?

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Jacob. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.
